# Triggering auto click within a website using Chrome Extension - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently trying to work out an experiment of mine with using this site:

http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/lunarglide-5-running-shoe/pid-726047/pgid-726952

What I am trying to accomplish is that, a default shoe size will be entered by user on the chrome extension end and once they hit this page, it will auto click the right size and click add to cart.

I have accomplished all this except it wont submit, it tells me to add a shoe size.

The Gif:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    checkForData();

    $('.add-to-cart').trigger('click');
});
function checkForData()
{   
    $('ul.footwear li').removeClass("selectBox-selected");
    chrome.storage.local.get('value', function (results) {
        $('ul.footwear').find('a').filter(function(idx, el){
            return $.trim($(this).text()) == $.trim(results.value);
        }).closest('li').addClass('selectBox-selected');
        $("a.footwear span.selectBox-label").text("("+$.trim(results.value)+")");
    });
}
```

if you look at `..}).closest('li').addClass('selectBox-selected');` I have tried using a trigger event as if it was clicked but nothing happens so I just gave it the class that it would have if someone clicked it.

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `select` input in there as well..

```
<select name="skuAndSize" class="size-dropdown mediumSelect footwear selectBox" style="display: none;">
         <option value=""></option>
            <option class="size-not-in-stock" name="skuId" value="3096786:6">6</option>
            <option class="size-not-in-stock" name="skuId" value="3096787:6.5">6.5</option>
            <option name="skuId" value="3096788:7"> 7</option>
            <option name="skuId" value="3096789:7.5" selected="true"> 7.5</option>
             ..........
             ..........
 </select>
```

My guess is you need to be selecting an option here before you try to submit. After all it's the variable here that will get posted in the form. What you appear to be doing is just changing the DOM UI.

Adding this might work:

```
$("select[name='skuAndSize']").val("3096789:7.5");
```

Comment: well how would I select it based on my value the user inputs, which for instance is 8